# Unable to fetch/pull code from bitbucket server due to password change

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

After password change on bit bucket server,

- I did not get the password prompt to enter the new password.
- Instead of asking for a new password, it keeps on trying to fetch the code from a bit bucket server using an old password.
- While fetching/pulling the code from the server, it tries to download the code multiple times with an old password.  After that continuously, it keeps on asking to fill captcha on the browser.

Is there any way in which we allow the server to pick a new password?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Go to tools and check authentication tab. Try refresh and enter new password. And check it works by fetching/pulling the code from server.

Solution 2: Go to %LocalAppData%/Atlassian --> Go to directory with name "SourceTree" --> Look for the file "passwd" and remove the encrypted text from this file. And try to fetch/pull the code from server on sourcetree. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your using Windows. In Windows password are saved in Windows Credential Manager.Type credential manager in the search box on the taskbar and select Credential Manager Control panel

Comment: This is same as that of Solution 1.